# Implementing Listeners which need to be execute after Main method is completed

Tags: java, web-services, rest, listener

Currently I'm working on a Core java project where am doing some REST API calls and getting its response back and manipulating it. I am in a situation where i need to implement Listeners to perform some actions after main method is completed.

```
public static void main(String[] args){

        try{    
                //Load Properties for Log4j
                myClass.loadProperties();

                //Reading url form Excel 
                Code to readExcel and store in map

                //Methods to do some webservice Calls - Got 200 as Response
                sendPostRequest(somedata,someUrl);          

                //Need to check the Status of the posted data by calling HTTP GET request by implementing the listners.

           }catch(Exception myException){
                 logger.error("Exception Occured: ",myException);
           }
    }
```

Immediately posting the request to server, i got 200 response. 
As soon as main method is completed, i need to have a listener method to send a GET request to get status of processing. The problem is processing time is completely dynmaic - sometimes within 3 mins, sometimes around 30 mins or even more, purely depends on the data posted to server.
PS: This is core java project which doesnt involves swings.

Any idea would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Why not just put the call to do the "getStatus" at the end of the main method?  Unless I've misunderstood your question.

Comment: that's what the solution i had. I need to wait certain amount of time before making a call to getstatus(). However, the waiting time is depends upon on the server to process the data which i have posted it. for example, if am posting very few sets of data, will get the response asap otherwise, it will take more time.  that being said, if i keep on calling the getStatus(), then it wouldn't be correct solution since calls to the server results in performance hits.

Comment: Can the server itself wait before sending a response? Get status calls are usually not expensive. This seems to be more of a problem in your servers design than your clients.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't modify the server the only possibility is to polling the server with several request to check the status of posted data.

If you can modify the server you can expose from the client a callback function and inform the server that he need to call that function when the request has been completed.

Both solutions works for requests of 3 minutes or also 3 days of execution.

Comment: i cant modify the server and yes, currently i had a plan to polling the server but this is overhead when the processing time is too high. Also, my requirement is to have a listeners implemented to achieve this!!

Comment: A listener must be invoked by someone. If you can't modify the server is not possible to write only a listener. Who will call it? You can write a poller that if the answer is completed call the listener.

Comment: from the code above, is there any possibility of triggering event that can invoke a listener? something like if response of the webserver is 200, that would trigger a listener? Also, any sugggestion on what type of listener can be implemented to achieve this? any code snippet would be much helpful. thanks